# Different behavior of consumed Python generators depending on implementation

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, generator

Consider the following code example. I defines two implementations of a generator which yields the numbers 0, 1, 2. My expectation is that SimpleClass().classgen behaves the same way as mygen. I know that generators can be consumed only once. That means one can only iterate over a generator once.

```
class SimpleClass(object):
    @property
    def classgen(self):
        for i in range(3):
            yield i

mygen = (p for p in range(3))


##### Test behavior
sc = SimpleClass()
print(type(sc.classgen))
print(type(mygen))
print("")

print("Iterating over new sc.classgen")
for i in sc.classgen:
    print(i)
print("")

print("Iterating over consumed sc.classgen")
for i in sc.classgen:
    print(i)
print("")


print("Iterating over new mygen")
for i in mygen:
    print(i)
print("")

print("Iterating over consumed mygen")
for i in mygen:
    print(i)
```

My expectation was that the first iteration over each of the generators print the numbers 0, 1, 2 and in fact that's what's happening. But then I would expect that when I iterate the second time over each generator that I will see no prints. That is true for the second loop over mygen, but the second loop over sc.classgen still prints the numbers 0, 1, 2. I cannot explain why that is. I thought generators can only be used once?

Comment: Because you made `classgen` a `@property`, each time something calls `sc.classgen` you get a new generator.  What's going on might be clearer if you remove `@property` and use `sc.classgen()` instead.  Then the difference between re-using the same generator (e.g. `mygen`) and getting a new one each time (e.g. `sc.classgen()`) would be more obvious.

Comment: You're right. Seeing it as a method instead of a property helps to understand what's happening. Obviously the property returns a new generator each time it is accessed. So it is definitely different than mygen. That makes sense. But what I find very confusing is that all type() calls return <class 'generator'> which suggest that they are the same thing, which is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not calling the same generator, if you assign `sc.classgen` to a variable, it will behave like you expect.

```
class SimpleClass(object):
    @property
    def classgen(self):
        for i in range(3):
            yield i

mygen = (p for p in range(3))


##### Test behavior
sc = SimpleClass()
print(type(sc.classgen))
print(type(mygen))
print("")

g = sc.classgen

print("Iterating over new sc.classgen")
for i in g:
    print(i)
print("")

print("Iterating over consumed sc.classgen")
for i in g:
    print(i)
print("")


print("Iterating over new mygen")
for i in mygen:
    print(i)
print("")

print("Iterating over consumed mygen")
for i in mygen:
    print(i)
```

As `classgen` property is a function, it will create a new one every time you access it.

Answer (score 1):

`@property` doesn't cache the return value of the method, therefore you are using different generators every time you call `sc.classgen`. You can test this:

```
import time


class SimpleClass(object):
    @property
    def the_time(self):
        return time.time()


sc = SimpleClass()

time1 = sc.the_time
time.sleep(2)
time2 = sc.the_time

print(time1 == time2)
> False
```